# Why do most microcontrollers not embed a 32k oscillator?

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, rtc

Why do most embedded systems use an external 32k oscillator?

Comment: real time clock

Comment: accuracy, accuracy

Comment: Needs a battery to justify it then it gets messy. Where do you stop? RS485 interface? RS232 interface?

Comment: Same reason they don't embed any capacitors. These things are hard to make small so they makes the whole chip expensive.

Comment: I think its a valid question. And in my opinion, the pretty obvious language barrier does not really justify the down votes.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I prefer my systems to run a bit faster than 32 kHz.

Comment: @Hearth You're in luck. There are plenty of crystals that run at 768Hz faster out there.

Comment: A lot of MCUs aimed at low power do embed a LF ostillator. (It needs an external resonator, i.e. crystal, though). Which ones are you thinking about that don't?

Answer (score 7):

To get < 50 ppm accuracy the Q of the resonator must be > 10k. This is done either with MEMs Ceramic crystals acting like a tuning fork or a Quartz Crystal ( too big)

This technology is not compatible with silicon chip materials or adds cost to a custom fabrication where it might not be needed.

However, if the 32kHz is just for low power and not high accuracy then the internal lower Q variable clocks are useful.

Answer (score 6):

There are some MCUs that do have a low frequency (like 10kHz or 32kHz nominal) oscillator so that the MCU can continue to do things like scan a keyboard while it is drawing little power. For example, the  MSP430FR2311 has a VLO function.
For such purposes, the actual frequency of the oscillator is not very important, +/-25% is fine, just accurate enough that debouncing and scanning and maybe LCD driving continues at more-or-less the right frequency.

The main reason to choose the 32.768kHz oscillator is to use an external 20ppm crystal that is made very cheaply for use in watches and clock mechanisms for use in a real-time clock. Of course 32,768 is used because a simple binary divider will give one pulse per second. For a real-time clock, +/-20ppm means that it will lose or gain a couple seconds a day without adjustment, which is not very good. (+/-20ppm = +/-0.002%)

The RC (resistor-capacitor) oscillators that can be built cheaply on a chip are more like +/-1% even after factory calibration, with commensurate bad temperature stability so they are completely useless for real-time clock purposes. They are barely good enough for reliable asynchronous serial communications.

The [above-mentione](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr2311.pdf?ts=1594666412649&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FMSP430FR2311%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Depd-msp-null-prodfolderdynamic-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253Dprodfolddynamic%2526ds_k%253DDYNAMIC%2BSEARCH%2BADS%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMI8sLipfPK6gIVA9bACh2jyAddEAAYASAAEgJlNPD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds)d VLO is not even good enough for that, nor is the internal 4.8MHz nominal oscillator (they're more like +/-20% or worse):

[image]

Note the snarky way they remind you of that with the "NOTE" regarding the (probably unexpected) 15% change in frequency by pointing you up to the table above where it explicitly says (by omission) that **nothing** is guaranteed (no maximum, no minimum).